# Expanding a data frame where one cell's data is comma separated

Tags: r

My data frame

```
DEALER ZIP
A      95605, 95811, ...
B      93291, 93277, ...
```

Since the ZIP column has more than one zip, I need this data cleaned so each zip gets its own row and the dealer for that row is still the one associated with it before the data was elongated.

```
Dealer
A  95605
A  95811
...
B  93291
B  93277
```

I know this code will split the data in a cell by a comma so that each zip has its own row, but how would I keep the associated Dealer?

```
unlist(strsplit(ZIP, ","))
```

Comment: Use `separate_rows`

Comment: @akrun what package is that in?

Comment: @akrun this is exactly what i needed, thanks!